# Set monitor refresh rate in an Xorg config

Tags: xorg, monitors

I have a monitor that supports 200hz refresh rate, and would like to be able to use that. When I run `xrandr`, it shows this option:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5560 x 1920, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 connected 2560x1080+0+420 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 814mm x 346mm
   2560x1080     59.98*+ 200.00   143.94   119.95    99.94    84.96  
   1400x1050     74.76    59.98
```

However when I change my Xorg configuration from:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "DP-1"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "2560x1080"
    Option      "Position" "0 420"
    Option      "Primary" "true"
EndSection
```

To:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "DP-1"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "2560x1080_200"
    Option      "Position" "0 420"
    Option      "Primary" "true"
EndSection
```

The monitor doesn't load, and doesn't warn/error in `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`.

Is there another way to set my monitors refresh rate in my Xorg config file?

Comment: Did you try to use somthing like `xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 2560x1080 --rate 200` to set the mode? What about other rates if this one doesn't work? Also, the mode name in the `xorg.conf` may be "2560x1080_200.00". Often the mode names are listed in the log file.

Comment: I can't test this here (because my current setup doesn't have EDID with different refresh rates), but does `xrandr --verbose -q` list the complete modenames for you? Inclusive underscore etc.?

Comment: A complete Xorg.log for the working mode (2560x1080 at 59.98 Hz) would help, just in case. Upload to a pastebin etc. and post the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Xorg.log` shows that you seem to have a NVidia card, however you still end up with the *modesetting* driver (which is the last-resort fallback). Both *nouveau* and *nv* are registered twice, which is also odd. Possibly your hardware is too new to be supported by nouveau. In any case, with this configuration you won't be able to use hardware acceleration (check with `glxinfo`).

It also seems like the default names of the modelines now include only vertical and horizontal resolution (see `xf86SetModeDefaultName` in [xf86Modes.c](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/hw/xfree86/modes/xf86Modes.c?h=server-1.18-branch)). IIRC they used to include the refresh frequency as well. I don't know what the reasoning was to exclude the frequency from the modeline name, but this means you know can't control from `xorg.conf` which modeline to use when there are several modelines with the same resolution but different refresh rate.

The only thing I can think of in this case is to include the modeline in `xorg.conf`, so you need something like

```
Section "Monitor"
    ...
    ModeLine "2560x1080@200.0" 598.40 2560 2608 2640 2720 1080 1083 1093 1100 +hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "2560x1080@200.0"
    ...
EndSection
```

Verify in `Xorg.log` that it correctly accepts and chooses this modeline; any problems will show up there.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works try setting the metamode option within the screen section.

```
Option "metamodes" "DP-1: 2560x1080_200 +0+0"
```